# Connecting Apollo Server to OrientDB Graph Database -- How to Connect?

Tags: graph

I'm attempting to create a web application that will rely on fetching data from a Graph Database. My graph database is hosted by [OrientDB 3.0](https://orientdb.com/). I'm trying to set up [Apollo Server](https://www.apollographql.com/server) on the same machine to handle clients' GraphQL-formatted queries.

However, I cannot find any documentation describing how one can connect an OrientDB database to an Apollo Server. The ["Getting Started"](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/getting-started.html) tutorial on the Apollo website sets up a constant to host the data rather than connecting to an external database:

[image]

And [this tutorial](https://blog.apollographql.com/tutorial-building-a-graphql-server-cddaa023c035) uses MongoDB and a module called "Mongoose" to create the connection between Apollo Server and the Database:

[image]

I'm rather new to the concepts for Graph Databases and GraphQL in particular, so I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious, or if I've perhaps misunderstood the relationship between Apollo and OrientDB. I've tried searching the web for "OrientDB" and "Apollo Server" and could not find any documentation linking the two together.

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Apollo docs use a constant instead of a DB because Apollo doesn't care what your data layer is.  MSSQL, MYSQL, Postgres, OrientDB, etc. etc.

You will need to use the Node driver for OrientDB (http://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/orientjs/OrientJS.html).  Should be similar to Mongoose.